# I'm trying to use a char created by public void Form1_KeyDown() in public Form1()

Tags: c#, class

I've been trying to make a program that makes you react to an image. In order to do that I need to use a char in the public Form1 created by a keypress. I don't want the image to show up at the key press.

Here's my code:

```
       public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackgroundImage = Directions.Images[8];

    }




    public void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //pijlrichting   links rechts boven onder c-links c-rechts c-boven c-onder
        //goede controls links rechts boven onder c-onder c-boven c-links c-rechts

        char c = Convert.ToChar(e.KeyCode);
        Random number = new Random();
        int direction = number.Next(0, 8);
        this.BackgroundImage = Directions.Images[direction];
        int[] controls = new int[] { 97, 100, 119, 115, 115, 119, 97, 100 };
        if(controls[direction] == c)
        {


        }

    }
```

Comment: What do the two comments mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a variable from the key press event in the Form1() , as Form1() is the constructor of the form , and always called first , and the key press event is called after the constructor.